# Room - Why use @Relation over @ForeignKey?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

My current goal is to have a one-to-many relation in my data.

From various tutorials I've come to understand that I have two main ways of doing this.

1. Create two entities and have the child use the `@ForeignKey` annotation
2. Create these two entities **and** an extra POJO, which uses `@Embedded` for the parent entity and `@Relation` to have a list of children tied to the parent

So, using Relation just seems like extra effort. Or am I missing something?
Is the big advantage of Relation this:

> When the Pojo is returned from a query, all of its relations are also fetched by Room.

Which would not be as easy with the first method?

Comment: in simple words, if you use relation, the room will do the heavy lifting of fetching the list (i.e your one to many relationships) while if you use only foreign key then you have to make that list yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Gautam's comment and further reading I now understand it this way:
`@Relation` is a convenience option to make retrieving connected entities easier. The price for this convenience is to give up the ability to control what happens on parent entry deletion and possibly other things.

Answer (score 1):

when you use @relation, it help the DBMS (database management system) to create a tree for sorting and storing data. so when you want to run any query it is very helpful.